# React Native Firebase refresh user record

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building a firebase login system with a verified email screen.

My problem is that I have a reload user button on the verified email screen that updates the user's credentials so that my root directory redirects the user to the AppStack if currentUser.emailVerified === true.
but the reload button isn't being triggered once pressed so that my root directory is still currentUser.emailVerified === false and not redirecting the user to the AppStack.

Login-System/context/AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../config';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 
  function sendVerification() {
    return currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
  }

  const getUser = () => auth.currentUser;

  const reloadUser = () => getUser().reload();

  const reload = async () => {
    try {
      await reloadUser();
      const user = getUser();
      setCurrentUser(user);
    } catch (error) {}
    return reload;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    loading,
    reload,
    sendVerification,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Login-System/screens/VerifyEmailScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import { View, Button } from '../components';
import { Colors } from '../config';

export const VerifyEmailScreen = () => {
  const { currentUser, reload, sendVerification } = useAuth();

  const handleSendVerification = async () => {
    try {
      await sendVerification();
    } catch (error) {}
    return handleSendVerification;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View isSafe style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.center}>
          <Text style={styles.screenTitle}>Check your email</Text>
          <Text style={styles.screenInfo}>{currentUser.email}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.screenInfo}>
            We sent you an email with instructions on how to verify your email
            address. Click on the link in the email to get started.
          </Text>

          <Button
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => handleSendVerification()}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Resend</Text>
          </Button>
          <Button style={styles.button} onPress={reload}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Done</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Which specific line in the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I've updated my question and added some more detail hopefully that helps with explaining my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some similar works to check if the user email is verified or not you can use this function:

```
export function getUserEmailVerified() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    return !!user ? (user.emailVerified ? 'Yes' : 'No') : 'No';
}
```

To trigger an email verification you can use this method. This method will trigger an email verification and refresh the user.

```
export function verificationEmail(email, onSuccess) {
    refreshUser();
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const finishAction = message => {
      onSuccess();
      showToast(message);
    };
  
    user
      .sendEmailVerification()
      .then(() => {
        refreshUser();
      })
      .catch(error => finishAction(error.message));
}
```

And to refresh the user you can use this method.

```
export function refreshUser() {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (!!user && !user?.emailVerified) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
        user?.reload().then();
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

You also need to use onUserChanged from firebase to detect whether user information is changed or not. It returns a listener if your user email verified field is changed anyway it will get here is an example.

```
export function onUserChanged(listener) {
    firebase.auth().onUserChanged(listener);
}
```

Comment: This is a great alternative to what I was suggesting, Thanks for the help :)